# Qt C++ Convert seconds to formatted string (hh:mm:ss)

Tags: c++, qt

As I said in title I need to convert seconds to hh:mm:ss

I tried this:

```
 ui->label->setText(QDateTime::fromTime_t(10).toString("hh:mm:ss"));
```

But default value for hours is always 01 but I need it to be 00. As result I should get 00:00:10 but I get 01:00:10.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your timezone is included in it thats why. Try this:

```
QDateTime::fromTime_t(10).toUTC().toString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I found this answer as best. Thank you.

Comment: In Qt5 use `fromSecsSinceEpoch` instead of `fromTime_t`. For durations longer than 24h you can adjust the formatter: `QDateTime::fromSecsSinceEpoch( 10, Qt::UTC ).toString( "d hh:mm:ss" );`. But as it is a date time and not a duration, using months won't work as intended. I.e., it is only useful for durations under 31 days. And in general this is not suited for durations as it tries to account for leap seconds and such thereby "falsifying" durations.

Answer (score 5):

There is no `QTime::fromTime_t`; possibly you're using `QDateTime::fromTime_t`, which accounts for time zones and daylight savings.

Instead you can use `QTime().addSecs(10).toString(...)`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using QDateTime::fromTime_t it was typo, sorry

Comment: If you want to use a `QTime` you need to use `QTime(0,0,0,0).addSecs(10).toString(...)`. Otherwise the `QTime` is initialized as NULL and wont print anything.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers work perfect when the number of seconds stays below 24 hours. For most usecases that is good enough. However for our usecase the timer went above 24 hours and reset to 00:00:00. Do note that the following code does not work for times of 100 hours or more. The number 2 in the arg method forces the string to be 2 characters.

```
int totalNumberOfSeconds = 90242; // nr of seconds more than 1 day.
int seconds = totalNumberOfSeconds % 60;
int minutes = (totalNumberOfSeconds / 60) % 60;
int hours = (totalNumberOfSeconds / 60 / 60);

QString timeString = QString("%1:%2:%3")
  .arg(hours, 2, 10, QChar('0'))
  .arg(minutes, 2, 10, QChar('0'))
  .arg(seconds, 2, 10, QChar('0'));
```

Answer (score 3):

In Qt 5 you can use QTime::fromMSecsSinceStartOfDay(int msecs).

```
ui->label->setText(QTime::fromMSecsSinceStartOfDay(10 * 1000).toString("hh:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: Note: This is limited to durations < 24h as per design of QTime.